# parse JSON object to custom class object in action script 3

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I want to parse JSON string to some my custom object in Action script 3. Is there some libs to do this. Or any ideas how can I make this. Thanx!

Here is an example what I want to receive:

```
{
    "result":{
        "birthday_at":"0000-00-00",
        "first_name":"Myname1",
        "level":5,
        "last_name":"MySurname",
        "gender":0
    },
    "cmd":"INFO",
    "service":{
        "code":0,
        "error_desc":""
    }
}
```

and class UserInfo:

```
public class UserInfo
{
  public Date birthday_at;
  public String first_name;
  public String last_name;
  public int level;
  public int gender;
}
```

And I want, to parse JSON string to fields of my class? How can I do this in an easiest way and in a right way? Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the class mentioned in the previous answer, you would simply need to do the following:

```
 var obj:Object = JSON.decode( jsonString );
 var user:UserInfo = new UserInfo();

 for ( var prop:String in obj )
    user[prop] = obj[prop];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var obj:Object = JSON.decode( jsonString );
var user:UserInfo = new UserInfo();

for ( var prop:String in obj )
    user[prop] = obj[prop];
```

This doesn't work for custom types with getters (read-only properties).
describeType can be used to get only the properties that can be set, but there are performance issues.

Darron Schall has a brilliant solution to take your JSON.parse(jsonString) plain object and convert it to a custom typed object.

https://github.com/darronschall/ObjectTranslator

Answer (score 2):

There is Adobe's JSON parser.

https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/tree/master/

`import com.adobe.serialization.json`